# Why I lost my master branch after executing `git checkout -b 3_1 `?

Tags: git, bash, version-control

I'm using Git Bash 2.9.0-64-bit in win7 64bit.

I created a git repository called lec_yaac. This is the related information about branch master:

> wen@wen-PC MINGW64 /d/Git/lec_yaac (master)

After I executed command `git checkout -b 3_1`,it changed to

> wen@wen-PC MINGW64 /d/Git/lec_yaac (3_1)

And I added and commmited some files.

But when I executed `git branch`,it only shows,

> - 3_1

There is nothing about branch master.

And `git checkout master` returns

> error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: I have undeleted it, sorry for it.tks@fedorqui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about a `master` branch. It is just like any other branch. And a branch is necessarily nothing but a pointer to a commit. So, the branch comes into the picture as soon as you make a commit.

You'd have gotten a `master` branch if you'd committed before creating a branch yourself.

What you did -
1. Created a repo
2. Created and switched to a new branch (`3_1`)
3. Committed to `3_1`

What you should have done -
1. Created a repo
2. Committed something to `master` (the default branch name)
3. Created and switched to a new branch (`3_1`)
4. Committed to `3_1`

If you still want a master branch, just create one.

```
git checkout -b master
```

Although this will now be pointing to the latest commit in your previous branch `3_1`

Answer (score 2):

When we initialize an empty git repo via `git init`, Git creates a `master` branch. However it's now merely a default ref that points to no commit, since there is not any commit yet. Run `cat .git/HEAD` and it outputs `ref: refs/heads/master`. After `git checkout -b 3_1`, the default ref `refs/heads/master` is replaced by `refs/heads/3_1`. When we make the root commit, `refs/heads/3_1` will point to it.

In another case, if we make a commit first before `git checkout -b 3_1`, we can see both `master` and `3_1` via `git branch`.